# Integrate Visual Studio online Git Repository to Android Studio 1.0.2

Tags: android, git, android-studio, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio online for my development process. And I want to integrate my Android Studio 1.0.2 codes in it. However, as I know Android Studio has no TFS Plugin. That's why, I want to use Git for source control.

How can I integrate Visual Studio Online Git repository to Android Studio 1.0.2. What are the steps that should I follow?

Comment: create a Team Project that uses Git as Source control. Navigate to the Source tab to grab the repository settings, clone the repo in Android Studio using the standard Git functionality in there.

Comment: how can I create a team project that uses Git as Source Control?, Where is the source tab?, What does cloning the repo in Android Studio mean?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First you need to create a Team Project in Visual Studio Online that is configured to use Git as it's Source Control Repository:

So, log on to you VSO account (or create one if you don't have one yet):

[image]

Create a new project from the dashboard:

[image]

In the "New Project Wizard" that comes up, make sure you select the use of Git:

[image]

Wait for the project to be created and click <kbd>Navigate to Project</kbd> when it's done. In the project's dashboard navigate to the Code tab:

[image]

And on the code tab you'll find your fresh Git repository.

[image]

You also get a notification that you must enable Basic Credentials so that git can connect (git doesn't support connecting to the Microsoft Account/Windows Live ID directly). If you haven't done so, now would be a good time.

Open your profile to set that up:

[image]

And configure Basic Credentials:

[image]

Now you're ready to connect to Android Studio and open your Git repo on Visual Studio Online:

[image]

Enter the Git repository location that was highlighted on the repository page before:

[image]

And your Alternate Credentials as you had defined them.

Android Studio will now ask you whether you want to create a project here. If you choose yes, you're all setup to start on your new project.

If you choose no, you can move an existing project into the repository root you just created and commit and push it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, I am looking forward to see second part

Comment: How can I import existing project INTO existing repository??

Comment: @josher932 clone the repo, copy paste the existing solution in the cloned repo,  commit.

Comment: Thanks!! @jessehouwing